# Spring MVC Controller never called from ajax Post

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have the page about.ftl which is invoked when I type localhost:8080/ui/about
and I have put the following block of code inside. Through SendToServlet() function I am trying to send the user info to my controller which is the OAuthController.java

```
 function SendToServlet(){
                            $.ajax({

                                        url: "localhost:8080/ui/about",
                                        type: "POST",                                            
                                        data: JSON.stringify({ user:jsonObj}),                                     
                                        contentType: 'application/json',
                                        success: function(result) {
                                            alert(done);
                                        },
                                        error: function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                                        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
                                        }
                                    });   
                                }
</script>
```

My Spring MVC Controller class code has the following implementation - all that it does is that it accepts the user's information and then sets up current user:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/about")
public class OAuthController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String post( @RequestBody   String items, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{




    String jsonResp = items;//sb.toString();
    ArrayList<String> usercredentials = new ArrayList<String>();
    usercredentials = parseJson(jsonResp);
    UserMethods usermethods = new UserMethods();
    usermethods.setCurrentUser (usercredentials);  
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return "{\"success\":\"\"}";


}

 public ArrayList<String> parseJson(String json){


}


}
```

My problem is that the controller is never invoked and actually I never see a Post request to be sent anywhere through Firebug. I've spent several days on it, but still no luck. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What HTTP status is coming back from the server. Could it be a 400 bad request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind value with your function. Your url `localhost:8080/ui/about/post` is just used to locate the controller but it will not execute any function because you didn't make a call to any function.

To call the function, you have to do like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ="/anyValue")
public String anyFunctionName(anyParam){...}
```

Above function will bind to url `localhost:8080/ui/about/anyValue`.

Comment: I  tried what you suggested updating url with localhost:8080/ui/about/control and @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ="/control")
public String post(anyParam){...} , but still receive the error message and I never see the post message to be sent.

Comment: I mean what I have defined to be returned by function SendToServlet when the function does not succeed, which is the jsonobject.

Comment: Yeah, but what exceptions are thrown. Put your stacktrace here.

Comment: Nothing at all. Through firebug I don't see any message to be sent and further more I don't receive any errors. This is strange, isn't it?

Comment: Well code works fine on Firefox after your suggestions but not in Chrome, that is why I was confused. Maybe it is the 'contentType' field that needs to be changed properly to work also with Chrome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to call it like this?

```
url: "localhost:8080/ui/about/post",
```

but first do this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/post")
```

Comment: Thank you. I also tried it but still get the error message by the function.

Comment: I have defined the variable jsonobj to be "alerted" every time the function returns error. This is what I mean by error.

Comment: I'm just thinking if you really need this method to return anything and if you need anything else (apart from items) as input parameters. Try to remove them and annotate method with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) rather than @ResponseBody. I'm not 100% sure it'll help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I just replaced @ResponseBody with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) . Do I need to do anything more? You know the strangest thing is that I never see a POST message to be leaving from client side to anywhere.. Is it normal? Maybe function SendToServlet() is not correct..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is pretty normal. For example submitting a form from client to server is POST. If what I said doesn't work, then I honestly don't know what else could :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last question: I replaced @ResponseBody with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) but did not further changes. I did not removed "HttpServletResponse response" , for example. Should I?

Comment: The thing is that I am not sure of it myself... I don't see if you're using it anywhere. Last time I worked on app with webservices I didn't have it along with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK), I suspect that this annotation is an alternative for what you're using, but I never researched it...

Answer (score 0):

How about try to add .html?Application won't add it automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by adding html? I have already an .ftl template where there is a button which when clicked the function SendToServlet() is called.